# Acceleration of masses connected by a leaning pole

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram

I'm looking at the following mechanical system, originally described in an exercise from Kleppner and Kolenkow (Problem 2.7, 2nd ed):

> A pole of negligible mass leans against a wall, at angle $\theta$ with the horizontal. Gravity is directed down. Each end carries a pivoted mass $M$. The wall and floor are frictionless. Assume that at the beginning of the motion the forces exerted by the rod are along the line of the rod. (As the motion progresses, the system rotates and the rod exerts sidewise forces.)

[image: problem-setup]

**My question:** The original problem asks us to find the acceleration of the masses only at $t=0$ when starting from rest. I've worked out the solution, but modeling the motion for *all* time requires knowledge of the force the pole is exerting on the masses for all time. So now I'm very curious: how can we find the force exerted by the pole for *all* time (as opposed to just when the system is at rest, as the problem asks)?

I ended up calculating that in the scenario described, the angle $\theta$, mass $M$, length $L$ of the pole, and force $F_p$ exerted by the pole on the two masses (presumably in the direction of the pole for all time) are related by the following differential equation:
$$
\dot\theta^2 = \frac 1 L \left(g\sin\theta - \frac{F_p}{M}\right)
$$
(for completeness, the derivation of this equation is given below, but I am not asking for verification of my work). This is a tricky ODE to solve! Obviously we can't have $F_p/M > g\sin\theta$. So $F_p = 0$ when $\theta = 0$ (which also makes intuitive physical sense). But then $F_p$ itself is changing in time.

How can we find the force $F_p$ if the system is in motion? Is such a calculation possible knowing only $L$, $M$, and the initial angle $\theta_0$?

**Derivation of above ODE:**

If $x$ and $y$ are the positions of the lower and upper ends of the pole respectively, then $x^2 + y^2 = L^2$, whence by twice-differentiating and dividing by $2$ we find
$$
x\ddot x + \dot x^2 + y\ddot y + \dot y^2 = 0
$$
Also, $x = L\cos\theta$ and $y = L\sin\theta$, so the above relation becomes:
$$
\ddot x L\cos\theta + \ddot y L\sin\theta + L^2\dot\theta^2 \sin^2\theta + L^2\dot\theta^2\cos^2\theta = 0,
$$
or
$$
\ddot x \cos\theta + \ddot y \sin\theta + L\dot\theta^2 = 0
$$
Let $F_p$ be the force of the pole, which has the same magnitude on both masses.

[image]

The forces $F_{\textrm{wall}}$ and $F_{\textrm{floor}}$ cancel with $F_p\cos\theta$ and $F_p\sin\theta+Mg$ respectively. The accelerations of the masses are $$\ddot x = M^{-1}F_p\cos\theta \quad \textrm{and} \quad \ddot y = M^{-1}F_p\sin\theta - g.$$ Plugging these into the boxed equation, we find:
$$
\frac{F_p}{M}\cos^2\theta + \frac{F_p}{M}\sin^2\theta - g\sin\theta + L\dot\theta^2 = 0,
$$
or
$$
\dot\theta^2 = \frac 1 L \left(g\sin\theta - \frac{F_p}{M}\right)
$$

**EDIT:** I am not looking for homework help (I've already solved the problem as stated), and I am not looking for someone to verify my work. If the moderators think the derivation of the ODE I've provided is inappropriate for this question, I'm happy to delete it from the post. I'm just wondering for my own curiosity if there's a way to model the force exerted by the pole for all time, not just when the system is at rest.

Comment: I'm not sure why this question was closed for being a homework question or asking someone to check my work, because I tried to be very clear that this question is neither of those things.

Comment: *modeling the motion for all time requires knowledge of the force the pole is exerting on the masses for all time* Have you tried using conservation of energy instead? It seems to me that that might be easier.

Comment: @Ghoster that occurred to me after writing the question, yes, though I was curious if it was possible to do it with Newtonian mechanics alone (conservation of energy is something I'm less comfortable with)